# Controller not working (except WeatherForecast) in .NET Core with React

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a fresh *.NET Core with React.js* project, which has this by default in `Program.cs`:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;
```

The provided `WeatherForecastController` works, i.e. this works:

```
https://localhost:44449/weatherforecast
```

But if I copy `WeatherForecastController.cs` and name it `MyNewController.cs` like this, it won't work.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyNewController : ControllerBase
{
   ...
```

`https://localhost:44449/mynew` returns the content of index.html.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `setupProxy.js` you have to add `/mynew` in the context:

```
const context =  [
    "/weatherforecast",
    "/mynew",
];

module.exports = function(app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};
```

Otherwise, the framework will interpret the url `/mynew` as a route to a screen and will handle it as such.

Comment: This was helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73937139/1984709