# Enable CORS in Asp.Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors

I am getting "*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:60261/api/student/?Name=qwwertyqwe&Age=21' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*"

Although the API is called and it is working as expected, but there is Error thrown at Chrome console.
Things I have done.

1. I have install CORS nuget package in the API.
2. I tried to add
   EnableCorsAttribute and config.EnableCors in WebAPIConfig.cs file
   but it is also showing error.

Below is the Chrome screenshot:
[image]

**EnableCorsAttribute Error **
[image]

**config.EnableCors Error **
[image]

Comment: is this a reactjs aspnet core project?

Comment: the API is in basic ASP.NET  and I am calling the API in an Angular Application.

Comment: i dont know if its the same with angular but with react you have to create a Proxy between api and front end ill add example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830055/proxy-conf-js-not-working-in-asp-net-core-app-with-angular

Comment: In my opinion, to fix this issue, you will need to add the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to the API response, indicating that requests from the specified origin are allowed

Comment: @IshworKhatiwada  Please elaborate, because I am also not able to add var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*") ;
config.EnableCors(corsAttr); in WebApiConfig.cs file.

Comment: During development, you don't need to configure CORS yet, https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server When you deploy to production, you can use a real reverse proxy (IIS+ARR or nginx).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `program.cs` or wherever your application is built

```
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials()
                            .WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));
```

Do note that the `UseCors()` needs to be called before `UseAuthentication()` and `UseAuthorization()`

Answer (score 0):

add the [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")] attribute to the API controller or method that you want to allow requests from other domains.
Or, In the WebAPIConfig.cs file, you can enable CORS globally.

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```