.NET 8 Angular and ASP.Net Core proxy config
I am working with the ASP.Net Core and Angular first time, so maybe the problem is easy to solve but I have not found a solution yet.
When the solution is create with the default visual studio template, there is an usual WeatherForecastController. I will not use that, so I had created my own ProductsController inheriting from ControllerBase.
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IProductsService _service;
        public ProductsController(ILogger<ProductsController> logger, IProductsService service)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _service = service;
        }

        // GET: Api/Products/GetAllProducts
        [HttpGet("GetAllProducts")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<ProductDto>>> GetAllProducts()
        {
            var allProducts = await Task.Run(() => _service.GetAllProducts());

            return allProducts;
        }
    }

So for this to work, I would also have to change the proxy.config.js
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
    env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'https://localhost:7010';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/api",
    ],
    target,
    secure: false
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;

I changed the context: [ "/weatherforecast", ] to context: [ "/api", ].
However API call did not work, I also tried ^/api and ^/api*, it did not work. I tired to pass the whole endpoint /api/Products/GetAllProducts but it did not work
When I use swagger to call the api endpoint it works, so at lest I am sure that it's not an backend issue.
Address from swagger - https://localhost:7010/api/Products/GetAllProducts. That's correct one.
Error from console in browser:
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "url": "https://127.0.0.1:4200/Api/Products/GetAllProducts",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure during parsing for https://127.0.0.1:4200/Api/Products/GetAllProducts",
    "error": {
        "error": {},
        "text": "<!doctype html>\r\n<html lang=\"en\">\r\n<head>\n  <script type=\"module\" src=\"/@vite/client\"></script>\n\r\n  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\r\n  <title>MerecruitmentClient</title>\r\n  <base href=\"/\">\r\n  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\r\n  <link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\">\r\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles.css\"></head>\r\n<body>\r\n  <app-root></app-root>\r\n<script src=\"polyfills.js\" type=\"module\"></script><script src=\"main.js\" type=\"module\"></script></body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
    }
}

It looks like the address is wrong, which is confirm by breakpoint in backend not triggering.
So I am almost sure that this problem is related to proxy I had similar one in React app, however I that case I was able to solve it on my own.

I tested with your code and reproduced the issue. The url is correct and I followed this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830055/proxy-conf-js-not-working-in-asp-net-core-app-with-angular and worked using "/api/**", however there is a lag before it works, I am still working on this.

Considering the npm action affect and the lag, I published the app and then start to test, and the behavior is different, it works correctly with your origin code. Could you please provide more details about how you test the project and your attemptions?
